# AHK variable folder path dependent on radio button choice

Tags: path, radio-button, autohotkey

Good day,

I'm trying to create a script for AutoHotKey (AHK). The script itself already works fine: a small GUI with two radio buttons for each color (black or white), but I want to have a single function and not a *gosub* for each color as it is now, because I want in the future to add much more colors.

Here is the GUI:

[image]

Here is the script:

```
Gui, Main:new

Gui, Add, GroupBox, x10 y6 w150 h100 R3, Color:
Gui, Add, Radio, Checked        vColor1 xp+10 yp+20,    Black
Gui, Add, Radio,                vColor2,                White

Gui, Add, Button, gEnter xp-11 yp+42, Enter

Gui, Show
return

Enter:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    Switch {
        Case Color1:
            gosub ColorBlack
        Case Color2:
            gosub ColorWhite
    }
    Gui, Hide
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

ColorBlack:
    Gui, ColorBlack: Add, Picture,, %A_ScriptDir%\color-black.png
    Gui, ColorBlack: Show
return

ColorWhite:
    Gui, ColorWhite: Add, Picture,, %A_ScriptDir%\color-white.png
    Gui, ColorWhite: Show
return
```

That's also why I need to keep this structure as it is now. Therefore, in order to have only one function (only *Color* instead of *ColorBlack* and *ColorWhite*) I would need to reference the certain part of the path to the radio button choice (so that it puts the color name in the right spot):

```
Color:
    Gui, ColorBlack: Add, Picture, x0 y0 w1920 h1920, %A_ScriptDir%\color-%color%.png
    Gui, ColorBlack: Show
return
```

The above one of course doesn't work – has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gui, Main:new
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x10 y6 w150 h100 R3, Color:
Gui, Add, Radio, Checked        vColor xp+10 yp+20  ,   Black   ; 1 -   you may use just one var for a radio button group, it'll be indexed
Gui, Add, Radio,                                    ,   White   ; 2
Gui, Add, Radio,                                    ,   Yellow  ; 3 and so on

Gui, Add, Button, gEnter xp-11 yp+42, Enter

Gui, Show

return

; Enter:
    ; Gui, Submit, NoHide
    ; Switch {

        ; Case Color1:  ;   just so you know, you dont need to use gosub with switch/case, you may just nest it under each case, but this would'nt be the best choice in this situtation
            ; Gui, ColorBlack: Add, Picture,, %A_ScriptDir%\color-black.png
            ; Gui, ColorBlack: Show

        ; Case Color2:
            ; Gui, ColorWhite: Add, Picture,, %A_ScriptDir%\color-white.png
            ; Gui, ColorWhite: Show

    ; }
    ; Gui, Hide
; return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp


Enter:

    Gui, Submit

    selected_color :=   color = 1 ; ternary operator to determine which color is selected | if ? then : else
                            ?   "black"
                    :   color = 2
                            ?   "white"
                    :           "yellow"
    Gui, Color:Add, Picture,,% A_ScriptDir "\color-" selected_color ".png"
    Gui, Color:Show


return

ColorGuiClose:  ;   destroy the color gui and show the main gui

    Gui, Color:Destroy
    Gui, Main:Show

Return
```